# Preventing trailing slash on domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, domain-name

I want my site to show up as **www.mysite.com**, not **www.mysite.com/**

Does Apache add a trailing slash after a domain name by default, or does the browser append it?  If I want to prevent this using an .htaccess, what would the url rewrite rule be?

Comment: That's how browser displays it -- nothing to do with web server.

Comment: @LazyOne- Then how come most sites don't have a trailing slash- using the same browser?

Comment: Trailing slash after domain name (like in your example) ... or after a folder name ?? -- That's a HUGE difference.

Comment: @LazyOne- Question is about trailing slash after domain name, not folders

Comment: Browser adds such slash automatically when requesting the URL. How it displaying in address bar it's a different story. For example: `www.adobe.com` -- type it in Firefox (Windows, 6.0.2), Google Chrome (Windows, 13.0.782.220 m) and Opera (Windows 11.51) -- the same URL they display differently.

Comment: LazyOne- thanks- if you make it an answer I can give you cred

Answer (score 4):

If you request:

`http://myhost.com`

The request needs to look like this in HTTP:
  GET / HTTP/1.0
  Host: myhost.com

For historical reasons, some browsers did append the slash because otherwise it translates to

GET <nothing> HTTP/1.0
  Host: myhost.com

Which would be an illegal request.

Note that:

`http://myhost.com/page`

is legal, because it translates to:

GET /page HTTP/1.0
  Host: myhost.com

Answer (score 3):

Browser adds such slash automatically when requesting the URL. *How it displaying in address bar it's a different story.*

**For example:** `www.adobe.com` -- type it in different browsers and see how they will display it:

- Firefox (Windows, 6.0.2) = `http://www.adobe.com/`
- Google Chrome (Windows, 13.0.782.220 m) = `www.adobe.com`
- Opera (Windows 11.51) = `www.adobe.com`
- Internet Explorer 9 = `http://www.adobe.com/`

Answer (score 2):

http://www.searchenginejournal.com/linking-issues-why-a-trailing-slash-in-the-url-does-matter/13021/

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slashforward/

URLs were initially used to model directories, so the trailing slash was required. I think if you don't have the trailing slash some webservers will not be able to find the content correctly.

Comment: @Anthony- Sorry, but this doesn't make sense, and doesn't answer the question.  The vast majority of domains don't include the trailing slash (StackOverflow.com included).  My question was why it was being auto-appended, and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by Anthony's first link, the slash is part of the address. Every domain (and not just "the vast majority") has a name resembling www.mysite.com, but this is just a domain name, not an URL. An URL is the address of a file, ie protocol+domainname+pathfile, so http://www.mysite.com/ is added the missing filename by DirectoryIndex and therefore is an URL, but http://www.mysite.com just doesn't mean anything since in this case the file path would be empty.
The fact that your browser doesn't display the boring parts of your URL is not related to your website's configuration.

If really the same browser behaves differently on different websites, I would be curious to know what browser and what websites you used.